# .da files are not created for gcov when accessed remotely

Tags: gcc, gcov, qnx

I'm trying to generate coverage info with gcov. The configuration is a little tricky. I have some of the testing running from the same machine. Others are implemented in Matlab and access the executables on the test-machine remotely. When the test files are executed from the same machine, the .da files are generated. However, no .da files are created when I run Matlab test files which use the executables on the test machine remotely. I'm accessing the test machine remotely with root access, all the privileges seem to be correct. Any idea why .da file are not generated when the executables are accessed remotely?

Answer (score 1):

Gcov generates .da files in the file system in which the executable resides. If your executable residing on the remote machine is the one enabled with coverage collection, you should look for .da files on the remote machine.